# AWS CDK pipeline python pass artifacts to next steps in cdk.stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying creating an AWS CodePipeline using AWS CDK in python.

cdk verson = 2.29.0

```py
import aws_cdk as cdk
from aws_cdk.pipelines import CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ShellStep
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_codecommit,
    pipelines,
    aws_codepipeline_actions,
    aws_codepipeline,
    aws_codebuild as codebuild,
    aws_iam as iam
    )
from my_pipeline.my_pipeline_app_stage import MyPipelineAppStage
from constructs import Construct
        
        
class MyPipelineStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, branch, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id  ,**kwargs)
        
        
        repository = aws_codecommit.Repository.from_repository_name(self,"cdk_pipeline", repository_name="repository-name")
        
        pipeline_source = CodePipelineSource.code_commit(repository,"master")
        pipeline =  CodePipeline(self, "Pipeline",
                        self_mutation=False,
                        pipeline_name="cdk_pipeline",
                        synth=ShellStep("Synth", 
                            input=pipeline_source,
                            commands=["npm install -g aws-cdk", 
                                      "python -m pip install -r requirements.txt", 
                                    "cdk synth"],
                             
                        ),
                        
                        )

        shell_step1 = pipelines.ShellStep("Creating csv file", commands=["touch casa.csv"])
        shell_step2 = pipelines.ShellStep("Creating", commands=["touch cisa.csv"])
        shell_step3 = pipelines.ShellStep("printing", commands=["ls"])
        
        ordered_steps = pipelines.Step.sequence([shell_step1, shell_step2, shell_step3])
        
        
        app_stage = pipeline.add_stage(MyPipelineAppStage(self, "test",env=env_EU),
                                       pre=ordered_steps,
                                       )
```

I don't know how to pass the output created from shell_step1 to shell_step2 and to shell_step3.

if I try to add the parameter `primary_output_directory` into the step shells like this:

```py
pipeline =  CodePipeline(self, "Pipeline",
                        self_mutation=False,
                        pipeline_name="cdk_pipeline",
                        synth=ShellStep("Synth", 
                            input=pipeline_source,
                            commands=["npm install -g aws-cdk", 
                                      "python -m pip install -r requirements.txt", 
                                    "cdk synth"],
                             primary_output_directory = "cdk.out"
                        ),
                        
                        )

        shell_step1 = pipelines.ShellStep("Creating csv file", commands=["touch casa.csv"], primary_output_directory = "cdk.out")
        shell_step2 = pipelines.ShellStep("Creating", commands=["touch cisa.csv"], primary_output_directory = "cdk.out")
        shell_step3 = pipelines.ShellStep("printing", commands=["ls"], primary_output_directory = "cdk.out")
        
        ordered_steps = pipelines.Step.sequence([shell_step1, shell_step2, shell_step3])
        
        
        app_stage = pipeline.add_stage(MyPipelineAppStage(self, "test",env=env_EU),
                                       pre=ordered_steps,
                                       )
```

I get this error

```
[Container] 2022/08/18 23:50:36 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching base directory path found for cdk.out
```

I don't know if it is necessary or not, I guess that I need to pass artifacts from one step to another but I cannot find how to do it

Comment: Ive not worked directly with the Pipelines library yet (still doing everything manually with the CodePipeline library) but my guess is that you shouldnt have multiple ShellSteps - Each shell step (from the docs) appears to basically be a L3 construct that obfuscates some of the setup necessary for a CodeBuild.  So your `commands` should be on one ShellStep as `commands=[touch casa.csv", "touch cisa.csv", "ls"]

Comment: As for your question, I leave this as a comment because Ive not worked too much with Pipelines, but https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.pipelines/ShellStep.html has an available attribute `outputs` so as I understand the AWS docs this means `my_shellstep = ShellStep(...)` into `my_shellstep.outputs` for getting the output of a given shell step. -- also there is `my_shellstep.primary_output` that just retrives a single output. -- however none of these are Artifacts, they are instead Filesets and im not sure how those interact with other CodePipeline stages

Comment: though the Fileset documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.pipelines/FileSet.html#aws_cdk.pipelines.FileSet says `artifacts.to_code_pipeline(your_FileSet)` is the necessary way, using the aws_artifacts module of CDK

Comment: @lynkfox you don't need them to be artifacts, since we're dealing with the abstract CDK pipelines API that has its own abstractions. It's very simple to do, the step itself can be passed as an input. Check my answer.

Comment: For L3 to L3 yes, but once you start moving out of L3 constructs back to the L2 ones, you need to use Arrifact type,  ot FileSystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a `ShellStep`'s output as an input for another `ShellStep`, pass it directly into the `input` prop of your `ShellStep`:

```py
shell_step_1 = pipelines.ShellStep("Creating csv file", input=pipeline_source, commands=["touch casa.csv"], primary_output_directory = "cdk.out")
shell_step_2 = pipelines.ShellStep("Creating", commands=["touch cisa.csv"], input=shell_step_1, primary_output_directory = ".")
```

`shell_step_2` will get the contents of `cdk.out` as input, so it will not have a `cdk.out` folder anymore.

This assumes that your source contains a `cdk.out` directory, which wouldn't be conventional. If you want to pass the output of the synth step to the Shell Step, you'll need to assign it to a variable and pass it as input:

```py
synth_step = ShellStep(
    "Synth", 
    input=pipeline_source,
    commands=[
        "npm install -g aws-cdk", 
        "python -m pip install -r requirements.txt", 
        "cdk synth"
    ],   
)
shell_step_1 = pipelines.ShellStep(
    "Creating csv file",
    input=synth_step,
    commands=["touch casa.csv"],
    primary_output_directory="cdk.out"
)
```

It's worth noting, though, that a single shell step can have multiple shell commands - you don't have to create a separate one for each command.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.ShellStep.html#initializer

Comment: I am still getting this error when I use `primary_output_directory = "cdk.out"` in shell_step_1:

`no matching base directory path found for cdk.out`

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: What's the source for your `shell_step_1`?